# Intacct API Calls From Browser

Tags: xml, api, web-services, intacct

I am trying to make an API call to the XML web services exposed by intacct through the browser as recommended [here](https://developer.intacct.com/wiki/web-services-api-30-calls). I would like to understand how do I pass the credentials (sender id/password) and the company details along with the xml request.

Anyone having an experience in connecting with intacct could provide his/her valuable inputs.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to figure this out. The credentials and the company details are passed as part of the xml request. The request include specific tags to pass this information. Please refer [this](https://developer.intacct.com/web-services/code-examples) link for more details.

Comment: can you please post your code solution so other could benefit?

Comment: I have updated the link that shows some code examples. That should help out